# Is it always the case that ${(z^a)}^b\ne z^{ab}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I've been lead to believe elsewhere that the following is true for $z\in \mathbb{C}$

$${(z^a)}^b\ne z^{ab}$$

This, of course, is not true for $z\in \mathbb{R}$

Is this true for ${(a,b)}\in \mathbb R $ as well as $\in \mathbb C$?

Could someone please explain this in *elementary* terms? Why is this so?

Comment: Your question is about what kind of values for $a,b$?

Comment: I'll modify the question.

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if my question has become too broad. I can't find the post that lead me to think about this. Perhaps I need to do some more research first.

Comment: if $a,b$ are not integers, both expressions are multivalued because $\log z$ is multivalued. There is no trouble when $z$ is positive real, one takes the principal value of the logarithm and forgets the others.

Comment: My understanding is that the left and right sides *are* equal for real $a$ and $b$.

Comment: The fact that the matrix product is not commutative is often expressed, by abuse of language, as “in general, $AB\ne BA$”, meaning that you can't count on the equality to hold; on the other hand it *can* happen that $AB=BA$ for two square matrices. So, if you found that “in general $(z^a)^b\ne z^{ab}$”, it's probably the same abuse of language.

Answer (score 7):

It is a bit unclear what you are asking. The formula
$$
(z^{a})^b = z^{ab}
$$
is not true for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ (and $a,b\in \mathbb{Q})$. See for example
$$
((-1)^2)^{1/2} = 1^{1/2} = 1 \\
(-1)^{2\cdot 1/2} = (-1)^1 = -1.
$$
Because of this, the same formula don't hold for $x\in \mathbb{C}$ since $-1\in\mathbb{C}$.

If you restrict $a$ and $b$ to the integers, then the formula holds for all $z\neq 0$ in the complex numbers.

If you restrict $a$ and $b$ to the natural numbers, then the formula holds for all complex numbers $z$.

Answer (score 2):

Both expressions have a countably infinite set of values when $a,b$ are real but, say, irrational. Define $L$ by
$$ - \pi < \operatorname{Im} L \leq \pi  $$ and
$$ \exp(L) = z. $$ Let's see, if $z = x + yi,$ and $L = M + N i,$ real $x,y,M,N,$ then $N y \geq 0$ and
$$ e^M = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \; \; \;  \mbox{AND} \; \; \; \tan N = \frac{y}{x}  $$ when $x,y \neq 0.$

The logs of $z$ are
$$ L + 2 k \pi i $$ so the values of $z^a$ are
$$ \exp (aL + 2ka \pi i). $$ The logarithms of these are, in a rather asymmetric manner,
$$ aL + 2ka \pi i + 2 n \pi i. $$
This says that all values of 
$$ (z^a)^b  $$ are
$$ \exp \left( abL + 2kab \pi i + 2n b \pi i \right)  $$ 
where the values of $z^{ab}$ are
$$ \exp \left( abL + 2kab \pi i  \right).  $$

One collection of values is a superset of the other. Further, the collection for $(z^a)^b$ and $(z^b)^a$ have considerable overlap but are different.